# maven install error - only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not \u0

Tags: eclipse, maven

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install
> (default-install) on project ecommerce-web: Failed to install metadata
> com.app:ecommerce-web/maven-metadata.xml: Could not parse metadata
> C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\com\app\ecommerce-web\maven-metadata-local.xml:
> only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not \u0
> (position: START_DOCUMENT seen \u0... @1:1) -> [Help 1]

there is nothing in my maven-metadata-local.xml

what is the problem?

Comment: I had this problem recently.  for me, the settings.xml file in the .m2 folder was corrupt. It started with plain text.  I'm not sure how it get corrupted as maven is running in a shared enviroment.  Just sharing my discovery in case some else has a problem.

Comment: The answers below can solve this issue, but I am just curious about how can this happen? I found the file blocking our project in the module that we written by ourselves.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The problem is in file `ecommerce-web/maven-metadata-local.xml`, it contains `char(0)` (or `null` char, or Unicode: `0x0`).
 Clean all local repository, or delete folder with `com.app:ecommerce-web` artifact

> There is nothing in my maven-metadata-local.xml

It's not true. Open your file with Notepad++ and you will see many `null`s

Comment: Had the same issue. maven-metadata-local.xml was full of NULL. It would be great if we knew why this happened. Will keep a close eye on this file.

Comment: I was new to maven and I was looking for file maven-metadata-local.xml

just to inform other you will be able to find maven-metadata-local.xml file in m2 folde, each for specific artifact

Comment: Another tip: Please find the `maven-metadata-local.xml` file and open it up using a text editor (ex: Notepad++), and select all the content, remove the content and save the file. Then, do a clean install. That's how I resolved this issue.

Answer (score 35):

Just go under

```
C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\com\app\ecommerce-web\
```

and delete `maven-metadata-local.xml`
Then do a clean install one more time, this should fix the problem and that's what I did.

Answer (score 4):

Delete all folders under app folder C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\com\app and then clean build project

Comment: This have been the perfect answer as deleting only the selected package from .m2 is helpful as compared to deleting the entire .m2 directory.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of character encoding issue. It doesn't appear when we open file in **UTF-8** encoded format.

To mitigate this issue, open file in **notepad++** and select encoding as "**Encode in ANSI**".
You will see many **BOM characters**. Remove them manually and save it again.
It works.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. I found the actual issue only when debug option (-X) was used with Maven.
`mvn clean install -DskipTests -X`

Then I deleted the contents of `maven-metadata-local`

Answer (score 0):

I also had this experience. The simple solution was deleting the relevant content of the **.m2** folder and **local repo** folder and build again using **mvn clean install** (Please make sure backup your important data :))

Answer (score -2):

Please backup your .m2 file when it working properly. In case you get above mentioned issue. you can replace the .m2 file which you have got backup. The issue can happen when corrupt the m2 file when occur the power cut kind of issue in advance. Then you wont get same issue again and again.