# Maven build error is occured in simple maven file

Tags: java, maven

[image]

I got the following error in my maven project. I'm following a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bDtZvYAT5Sc&t=326s). And the maven file is rather simple.

```
Project build error: Non-parseable POM /home/isuru/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/1.5.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-
 dependencies-1.5.3.RELEASE.pom: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not t (position: START_DOCUMENT seen t... @1:1)
```

Here is the maven file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>uk.co.stableweb.quickstart</groupId>
    <artifactId>course-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Course API Sample App</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

In another stackoverflow post there was a post regarding file format, so I changed file format to utf-8 as well.

[image]

Any suggestion to solve this problem will be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: The error message clearly indicates that the problem is in the /home/isuru/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/1.5.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-1.5.3.RELEASE.pom file. You should inspect its contents to check why it is not a "valid pom".

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have copied some invisible metacharacters in your pom. That  happens when you copy dependencies from websites sometimes. Try to remove linebreaks and whitespaces from the pom file between your tags, preferably ALL of them, and then let your IDE simply reformat the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to,

```
C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\com\app\ecommerce-web\
```

and delete `maven-metadata-local.xml` then do a clean install one more time, this should fix the problem

Comment: Then why it is included in this project? https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot/edit/master/complete/pom.xml Sorry, I'm new to maven.

Comment: @Isuru Its just a xml declaration which is not cumpulsory, check [here](https://maven.apache.org/developers/conventions/code.html)  Please try this solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929633/maven-install-error-only-whitespace-content-allowed-before-start-tag-and-not)