# Whitespace Errors in Maven when Installing Selenium POM

Tags: java, apache, maven, selenium

I am trying to follow [these instructions](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-webdriver) to get started with Selenium. I downloaded and installed Maven on my mac but when trying to use `mvn clean install` with the suggested pom.xml file I get the following errors:

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM /Users/JB/Documents/Maven/Selenium-Build/pom.xml: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not { (position: START_DOCUMENT seen {... @1:1)  @ line 1, column 1
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project  (/Users/JB/Documents/Maven/Selenium-Build/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-parseable POM /Users/JB/Documents/Maven/Selenium-Build/pom.xml: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not { (position: START_DOCUMENT seen {... @1:1)  @ line 1, column 1 -> [Help 2]
```

Here is the pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MySel20Proj</groupId>
    <artifactId>MySel20Proj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

What am I missing here? I've tried the POM looks like it is structured the same as many of the examples I found when researching this issue. I don't see the whitespace it is complaing about at the start of the document. I am not familiar with Maven, and am really in need of some help.

Comment: this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929633/maven-install-error-only-whitespace-content-allowed-before-start-tag-and-not

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this kind of thing happen when copy-and-paste ends up putting a non-printing character at the very beginning of the file, before that initial <.  You don't see it - but Maven complains.  If you are in Linux, try "cat -v pom.xml" to see if there are any such characters in there...

Comment: Thank you. That revealed some hidden characters which i used nano to delete. I tried running again and got a different pointing out another location in the code. I'm not sure why, but there were backslashes added after each line of code and a curly brace at the end. I used vim to delete all of those and the project compiled successfully.